# UIAlertView action and cancel buttons 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

I've been researching and analyzing and I realize that the buttons from the UIAlertView don't have a similarity between buttons and actions.

---

[image: Ex. 01]
*The left button does the main action and the right button dismisses the alert.*

[image: Ex. 02]
*The left button dismisses the alert and the right button does the main action.*

---

In the documentation, the "cancelButtonTitle" (right button) is `the title of the cancel button`, but it doesn't clarify if this button is really the one that dismisses the alert or the one that does the main action.

Well, my question is: there's pattern about buttons or anyone can do any action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple HIG:

> A button that initiates an action is furthest to the right. This rightmost button, called the action button, confirms the main point of the dialog. The Cancel button is to the left of the action button.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for the explanation. It's really weird that Apple don't followed the HIG with their native apps. :P

Comment: Apple breaks their own rules all the time. Notice the positioning of the Rest and Don't Reset buttons in the Simulator's **Reset Content And Settings**. And that's on the Mac OS side, where these rules have been established for *decades*.

Comment: @StevenFisher It's to ensure you do not click the default button inadvertently and lose all your data. Or they think most people open that dialog only to look at it and do not actually want to reset, so that "don't reset" is the main action for them :)

Comment: Yeah, that's their thinking. But the consequence is I click the safe button position when I want to back out and lose my data, or the dangerous button position when I want to reset and wonder why it didn't work. :)